# SqliteConnection 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' for in memory database

Tags: c#

I'm making a factory to get a connection, like so, for testing:

```
class ConnectionFactory: IDisposable
{
    // ...

    public ItemsContext CreateContextForSQLite()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>().UseSqlite(connection).Options;
        var context = new ItemsContext(option);

        // ...

        return context;
    }
}
```

And in my client code I'm using it like

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
var context = factory.CreateContextForSQLite();
```

But this returns an error

```
  Message: 
    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Stack Trace: 
    SqliteConnection.Open()
    ConnectionFactory.CreateContextForSQLite() line 32
    TestClass.DatabaseExists() line 30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `option`  (`new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>().UseSqlite(connection).Options;` returns `null`) is null so that

```
var context = new ItemsContext(option);
```

gives null reference error

Comment: The exception is thrown from the connection opener, which fails the rest.

Comment: what is connection opener?